# Java Scanner - Ignore Subsequent Letters

Tags: java, regex, parsing, java.util.scanner

My program needs to accept integer numbers, individual characters, or one specific string (I'll use `"pear"` for this example). Whilst each of these can be separated by whitespace, there shouldn't be any need to.

Currently, my parsing code, which relies on a `Scanner`, looks something like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    if (scanner.hasNext("\\s+")) {
        // Ignore whitespace…

    } else if (scanner.hasNext("[-]?\\d+")) {
        // Get a number
        String nextNumberString = scanner.next("[-]?\\d+");
        // Process the string representing the number…

    } else if (scanner.hasNext("pear")) {
        scanner.next("pear");
        // Do something special…

    } else {
        // Get the next character
        Pattern oldDelimiter = scanner.delimiter();
        scanner.useDelimiter("");
        String nextCharAsString = scanner.next();
        scanner.useDelimiter(oldDelimiter);

        char nextCharacter = nextCharAsString.charAt(0);

        if (Character.isWhitespace(nextCharacter)) {
            // Ignore whitespace…
        } else {
            // Process character…
        }

    }
}
```

At present, my program will accept input like `123 d 456 r pear` without any problems. However, it should also accept the same input without any whitespace (`123d456rpear`), and interpret it the same way, and with my current code, the individual digits are incorrectly interpreted as characters.

I feel like the cause might be the regular expressions that I'm using. However, adding `.*` to the end of them will cause all of the subsequent characters to be parsed, along with the input that I'm trying to parse. For example, `[-]?\d+.*` will try to parse the entirety of `123d456rpear` as a number, when I really just want `123`, leaving the rest to be parsed later. I've also tried wrapping my desired input into a group, and then appending `?` or `{1}`, which hasn't worked, either.

I've also experimented with `scanner.findInLine()`, but in my testing, this doesn't seem to work either. For example, when I tried this, `pearpear` would cause an infinite loop, despite my attempts to skip the first instance of `pear`.

I've also tried setting the delimiter to `""`, like I do when extracting individual characters (which, in that case, works as expected). However, this causes each individual number to be processed individually, parsing `1`, `2`, and `3` instead of `123`. `pear` also gets interpreted as individual characters.

So, could someone help me figure out where I'm going wrong? Does this issue lie with my regular expressions? Am I using the wrong methods? Or am I misunderstanding how the `Scanner` class is designed to work?

Comment: How is the program supposed to make a difference between a single character and a String like pear?

Comment: Generally, a single character is interpreted as some sort of command, but I have to include an easter egg if this special string is typed in. This is why I'm checking for this special string before interpreting the input as individual characters.

Comment: @YassinHajaj The string is only a specific magic string, not strings in general. So the parsers gives preference to parsing the string "pear" if it can be found, otherwise individual characters are read, e.g.,  "pead" would be parsed as "p","e","a","d", but "peard" would be parsed as "pear","d".

Comment: Exactly, thanks @IngoBürk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my understanding the idea of the Scanner class is to extract tokens and to throw the delimiters away. But you don't want to throw anything away but whitespaces. However whitespaces are not required in your input. Here is an implementation idea by using an outer and an inner Scanner. The outer tokenizes at whitespaces - if any. The inner uses `findInLine()` to bypass delimiters at all.

> findInLine
>
> Attempts to find the next occurrence of a pattern constructed from the
>   specified string, ignoring delimiters.

```
public void scan(Scanner scanner) {
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String next = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("opening inner scanner: " + next);
        Scanner innerScanner = new Scanner(next);
        do {
            next = innerScanner.findInLine("([-]?\\d+)|(pear)|([a-zA-Z])");
            if (next == null) {
                // Nothing useful in there
            } else if (next.equals("pear")) {
                System.out.println("pear");
            } else if (next.matches("[a-zA-Z]")) {
                System.out.println("char: " + next);
            } else {
                System.out.println("number: " + next);
            }
        } while (next != null);
        innerScanner.close();
    }
}

public void run() {
    scan(new Scanner("123 d 456 pear"));
    scan(new Scanner("123d456pear"));
}
```

The output of the `run()` method is as follows:

```
opening inner scanner: 123
number: 123
opening inner scanner: d
char: d
opening inner scanner: 456
number: 456
opening inner scanner: pear
pear
opening inner scanner: 123d456pear
number: 123
char: d
number: 456
pear
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this! Sorry for being slow to respond, but I ended up working backwards from this code, to something that works with only one scanner. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great. Do you think it might be useful to  add your one-scanner-solution to the question or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Well `the individual digits are incorrectly interpreted as characters` because `hasNext` method of Scanner extracts the token from the given by the [delimiter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#delimiter--) which defaults to whitespace

From java docs

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern,
>   which by default matches whitespace. The resulting tokens may then be
>   converted into values of different types using the various next
>   methods

Hence the whole `123d456rpear` is extracted which is not a number but a string

Comment: This might be true, but it doesn't help me get any closer to the desired functionality…

Comment: To my understanding the idea of the Scanner class is to extract tokens and to throw the delimiters away. That's what Anupam quoted. But you don't want to throw anything away at all if you don't have whitespaces in your input. So the Scanner might be the wrong class to start with or only  `findInLine()` is useful for your problem.